# How to get the Longitude and Latitude from a map in react-native?

Tags: react-native, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to capture the Longitude and Latitude of the user from Google maps or open street maps. Could anybody let me know that is it possible to do in react-native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know you can't get user location from the Map itself. You can use [Geolocation API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html) of react-native.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo_success, geo_error?, geo_options?)
```

// or

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geo_success, geo_error?, geo_options?)
```